# For a person who doesn't work but got the necessary money. How the bank statement should be when applying for uk tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a student and I want to apply for a UK tourist visa. A month ago my parents sent me the money for my trip (as a gift). So if I apply for a UK tourist visa, is it okay that my only source of revenue is that money? And what should be on the bank statement?

Comment: You are very likely to be refused the visa, because your parents deposited the money in your account. This is a very common mistake. You should not have the money sent to you until after you have obtained the visa.

Comment: The only thing you can do in this scenario is tell the truth about where the money came from and why it was given. You will also need to provide evidence that your parents were the source of the money (eg their bank statements showing the transfer to yours) and that they obtained the money legally (eg their pay slips). Even then, you may be refused on ‘funds parking’ grounds. See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Answer (score 12):

Your bank statements should obviously be the truth, so there is no question **what** is on them.

- To get a visa approved, your finances should show a stable pattern of reasonable income and expenditures, as explained in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105). Income does not have to be wages, but it must be transparent and legal. Are you getting an allowance from your parents? It would help if that was a monthly deposit and not cash.
- **If** you have large one-time inflows of cash, they **must** be explained.
- Normally you would explain that *you* can afford the visit from *your* income. As a student without job, you would have to explain that *your parents* can afford to give you the visit as a gift from *their* income. That means showing they're your parents and not just distant relatives, and what their financial situation is: income, expenditure, bank statements.
- You still have to include your own bank statements, to show that you have a regular lifestyle consistent with your means.

Comment: To make it clear, that means the OP will most probably have to include their parent's bank statements, as they de facto the sponsors of the trip.