# Bank statement for UK short term study visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, study, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm an Egyptian medical student and I'm planning to undertake a medical elective for 6 weeks in the UK. I have a specific question regarding the bank statement that I'm going to provide in the visa application...
I'm applying with my own bank account which has more than enough to cover my expenses (around £1800). I deposited £1400 of them 5 months ago, and the account is still active and I use it for recurrent minor expenses and deposits. I'm concerned this deposit will raise suspicion for being a used as a funds parking. Also not to forget to mention some points here..

- I've traveled last year to the UK for 3 weeks for a medical summer school but I used another account (also mine) which didn't have such large deposits, and I also included HR letters for both of my parent, without mentioning they are sponsoring me, and got accepted right away.
- The situation now is that my parents are retired this year and they've lent my the money from their savings for my trip.

So, would this recent travel history improve my situation and cover for this large deposit? and do I need also to include my parents' last year's HR letters?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137250/for-a-person-who-doesnt-work-but-got-the-necessary-money-how-the-bank-statemen